# MVVM communication with Objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm currently trying to create an application with Prism and I have some problems with communication between modules.

I have a StatusModule which basically shows Statusmessages, but can also show the user that some work is in progress (indeterminate), show different icons, show / hide the control and so on.

For that normally i'd use a status object that has all these properties and use it as a parameter, but because in prism strong coupling is advised I don't know how I should do it.

Creating 4-5 Events for every property is probably bad practice, .. i also thought of creating an interface in my "Interaction" Module where the event's and resources are.

What would you guys recommend?

Comment: You can use event aggregator to communicate between modules

Comment: Yeah but eventaggregator only support's basic type's, correct? So I'd have to create a event for every property i have (Show, AutoHide, Message, ... )

Comment: You can expose status object with event aggregator

Comment: Yes but that would mean I'd need a "Status" class either in the "Interaction" or in the "Status" DLL, correct? An interface wouldn't be enough because the module that tries to set a status has to instantiate a class to publish. 

At the moment I'm creating an IStatus object as the context of the StatusRegion and suscribing to notifypropertychanged event's

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in my blog post about [Simplifying Prism's EventAggregator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/)?

Answer (score 0):

Many events for status might indeed not be the best solution; however if there's one or two that are used a lot (like showing a status message in a statusbar), I would expose them as events anyway for convenience.

For the rest, you can expose the StatusModule, or rather an interface IStatusModule that is implemented by StatusModule, via MEF or Unity depending on what you use. This way any component that wants to show status imports the IStatusModule and uses it.